# HTML onclick() help, image and paragraph together?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm hoping this is relatively simple to fix. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I want a button in HTML to show a paragraph, and then a second button to combine a paragraph and an image.
It spits the result underneath the divider, with a default underneath beforehand. Got that part to work after seeing some examples. I also got it to combine the text, so that seems fine, but when I try and stick in an image, I get nothing.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
   <p>
     Filler text here.
   </p>
    <input type="button" value="Test 1"
          onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                     'Testing words.';">
    <input type="button" value="Test 2"
          onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                     'Testing combining words ' +
                     'and images.' +
                     '<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/afg90RRXB-Ah7-9IZZU-uj9iPztl4Y6gDUAtR-02O5jNIcTll2XlDJdXd3AZKtAlRPcBZ_2iZiGJhRvko-k2GOd9FSFuNYw" alt="W3Schools.com">';">
   <hr>
   <div id="outputDiv">
     Testing output.
   </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&quot;` instead of `"` inside the `onclick` attribute:

```html
  <p>
     Filler text here.
   </p>
    <input type="button" value="Test 1"
          onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                     'Testing words.';">
    <input type="button" value="Test 2"
          onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                     'Testing combining words ' +
                     'and images.' +
                     '<img src=&quot;https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/afg90RRXB-Ah7-9IZZU-uj9iPztl4Y6gDUAtR-02O5jNIcTll2XlDJdXd3AZKtAlRPcBZ_2iZiGJhRvko-k2GOd9FSFuNYw&quot; alt=&quot;W3Schools.com&quot;>';">
   <hr>
   <div id="outputDiv">
     Testing output.
   </div>
```

But this is *really really ugly*. How about attaching the event listener with JavaScript instead?

```js
const [btn1, btn2] = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
btn1.onclick = () => outputDiv.innerHTML = 'Testing words.';
btn2.onclick = () => outputDiv.innerHTML = 'Testing combining words and images.' +
  '<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/afg90RRXB-Ah7-9IZZU-uj9iPztl4Y6gDUAtR-02O5jNIcTll2XlDJdXd3AZKtAlRPcBZ_2iZiGJhRvko-k2GOd9FSFuNYw" alt="W3Schools.com">';
```

```html
<p>
  Filler text here.
</p>
<input type="button" value="Test 1">
<input type="button" value="Test 2"">
<hr>
<div id="outputDiv">
  Testing output.
</div>
```

I'd highly recommend avoiding inline handlers when possible - the escaping required and their crazy scope chain makes code so much harder to read and write than it needs to be.

Comment: That happy face is making me nostalgic.

Comment: That did the trick. Wow, so simple... I feel like a buffoon. Thank you very much!

Comment: Truth be told I've been hesitant to getting into javascript embedded in the html. I know I'll have to, but I've just been pushing it back until I got a foothold in html first.

Comment: @ConnerMcClellan You *don't* have to - I have never encountered a situation when an inline handler is required to solve a problem, and I've coded a *lot*. Put your JS in a `<script>` tag instead, ideally in a separate file.